Delphi Rest Client Authorization with Client Certificates
I am working on a Delphi (11.3) project where there is a need to make HTTP Requests (PUT, GET, PATCH) to a service that requires Client authentication solely with certificate files and using TLS version 1.2 at minimum.
There are .csr, .p12, .key and .pem client certificate files and a .pem root certificate file.
The problem is that the company policy is to use the REST client, but have been unable to locate useful information, guides or examples on how to implement this kind of authentication with the REST client.

Please read the question properly first before posting such an answer. We are not talking about basic authentication here, but client authentication with certificates.
